# How to make Qualtrics heat map question use graphic previously uploaded by participants in another block

Tags: heatmap, qualtrics

Working on a qualtrics survey where Q12 involves the participant uploading a photo. We will be doing surveys in the field and thus the participant will most likely take a picture with their phone.

I would like to create a subsequent heat map question, where the participant can mark a point on the photo they just took/uploaded. I have managed to get the uploaded graphic to display statically by adding `<img src="${q://QID12/UploadedFileLink}" alt="Uploaded image">` in the html view of the question, but cannot figure out how to use that photo as the base for the heat map question so they can mark a point.
Is this posible?

Thank you!